# How can I improve the trackpad response on a Macbook Pro 11.5?

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a Macbook Pro 11.5. It all works fine out of the box, but I have few problems. The trackpad sensitivity is very low, so when I make very fine movements on the trackpad I see no movement of the cursor.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: i have removed one of the questions, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I know next to nothing about touchpad stuff in Ubuntu, but it's always a good idea to look at the side bar for related questions: [Sluggish/unresponsive trackpad on MacBook Pro](/q/80488/175814). Another start would be a search for the question with the [same keywords as yours](/questions/tagged/macbook+touchpad). With the relatively new “Wayland” display and input device server (the default in 17.10 although you can revert to “X.org”) you may find it difficult to find quality answers due its novelty.